# Polars Supertype on date when shift_and_fill

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have the following two snippets that should do the same (ignore the edge case where 0 index is `None`):

```py
date_to_fill = df['time_start'][0]
df['time_start'] = df['time_start'].shift_and_fill(window_size, date_to_fill)
```

```py
df['time_start'] = df['time_start'].shift(window_size)
df['time_start'].fill_null("backward")
```

In both cases, the series is shifted by `window_size` positions, and then the first `0..window_size` positions get filled with the initial data. However, when I run the former I get a polars exception:

```
exceptions.ComputeError: Failed to determine supertype of Datetime(Nanoseconds, Some("UTC")) and Datetime(Microseconds, None)
```

The exception is not thrown in the second snippet, though the same data is taken (or is the dt converted when taken as a singular variable)

**EDIT: Test Data**

```
[{'time_start': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 10, 43, 52),
  'time_end': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 10, 43, 7),
  'value': None,
  'min_value': 80,
  'max_value': 98,
  'avg_value': 88.66666666666667},
 {'time_start': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 10, 43, 49),
  'time_end': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 10, 43, 2),
  'value': 79,
  'min_value': 79,
  'max_value': 80,
  'avg_value': 82.33333333333333},
 {'time_start': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 10, 43, 21),
  'time_end': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 10, 43),
  'value': 79,
  'min_value': 79,
  'max_value': 80,
  'avg_value': 79.33333333333333}]
```

This is Polars 0.13.58

Comment: Could you provide a small set of starting data that would lead to the error?  Just a few rows.  This will help me replicate your error.  I do have a hunch as to what is going wrong ... but I need to confirm two things.  Also, could you include which version of Polars that you are using?

Comment: It's Polars 0.13.58, I've attached some test data (I'm not sure on how to export with UTC data)

Comment: Thanks.  I've logged a feature request that will explain why you are getting the error.  (https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/4174)  For now, I would use the backward fill technique.

Comment: As of Polars 0.13.59, this is fixed.  When a Python `datetime` object is compared to a Polars `Datetime` column that has a time zone, Polars will match the Python `datetime` object to the time zone of the `Datetime` column.